# make menuconfig hangs when trying to compile linux kernel 6.1.44

Tags: gcc, makefile, build, linux-kernel, debian

I am trying to compile linux kernel 6.1 on Debian 12.

I have installed the build environment:

```
apt-get install build-essential bc libncurses-dev libssl-dev libelf-dev bison flex
```

Now when I run make menuconfig, I get this output ant then it hangs forever:

```
  ~/linux-6.1.44: make menuconfig
  HOSTCC  scripts/basic/fixdep
  UPD     scripts/kconfig/mconf-cfg
  HOSTCC  scripts/kconfig/mconf.o
  HOSTCC  scripts/kconfig/lxdialog/checklist.o
  HOSTCC  scripts/kconfig/lxdialog/inputbox.o
  HOSTCC  scripts/kconfig/lxdialog/menubox.o
  HOSTCC  scripts/kconfig/lxdialog/textbox.o
  HOSTCC  scripts/kconfig/lxdialog/util.o
  HOSTCC  scripts/kconfig/lxdialog/yesno.o
  HOSTCC  scripts/kconfig/confdata.o
  HOSTCC  scripts/kconfig/expr.o
  LEX     scripts/kconfig/lexer.lex.c
  YACC    scripts/kconfig/parser.tab.[ch]
  HOSTCC  scripts/kconfig/lexer.lex.o
  HOSTCC  scripts/kconfig/menu.o
  HOSTCC  scripts/kconfig/parser.tab.o
  HOSTCC  scripts/kconfig/preprocess.o
  HOSTCC  scripts/kconfig/symbol.o
  HOSTCC  scripts/kconfig/util.o
  HOSTLD  scripts/kconfig/mconf
```

I have ncurses installed:

```
# dpkg -l | grep ncurses
libncurses-dev
libncurses6
libncursesw6
ncurses-base
ncurses-bin
```

am I still missing some component of the build system ?

Comment: You can generate a more verbose output using `make V=1 menuconfig`. Maybe you'll identify the command that is stuck. `ps` could also help you see if any process is stuck.